# How to handle the type of the theano

Tags: python, theano

I have a matrix 'y' and I want to add one of number in every row of y.Then I set a matrix 'x' which the first column set the one I want to add. I use the following code:

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x = T.matrix('x')
y = T.matrix('y')
z = T.sum(y[T.arange(1,5),x[:,0]])

f = theano.function(inputs=[x,y],outputs=z)

x = numpy.asarray([[1],[2],[3],[4],[0]])
y = numpy.ones(5,5)
print(f([x,y]))
```

But this cann't work. There will be a grammar error. why dosen't this code work?

Comment: can you give some examples input-output?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I want to write a function, the input is two matrix, suppose the first matrix is a = numpy.asarray([[1,0,0,0,0],[0,2,0,0,0],[0,0,3,0,0],[0,0,0,4,0],[0,0,0,0,5]]), and I want to add the diagnose of this matrix, and I set the second matrix is b = numpy.asarray([[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]]), that means add first number in first row, second number in second row and so on...For this example , the answer is 15...That's what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

there are some problems in your code. first, define your data type carefully and then becareful when using `[]` bracket (see how you just make another array when you call your function by `f([x,y])`)

so, after I modify your code become:

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x = T.imatrix('x') #define integer matrix
y = T.imatrix('y')
z = T.sum(y[T.arange(5),x[:,0]])

f = theano.function(inputs=[x,y],outputs=z)

x = numpy.asarray([[1],[2],[3],[4],[0]])
y = numpy.ones((5,5),dtype="int32") #define integer array
print(f(x,y)) #remove square bracket
```

Hope it helps

Comment: your welcome :) I see you are new in stack overflow, If you feel my answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.